# Problema al obtener la ubicación del usuario en segundo plano en React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Estoy tratando de seguir obteniendo la ubicación del usuario en segundo plano. ¿Por qué al apagar la pantalla o minimizar la aplicación, dejo de obtener los datos correspondientes a la ubicación por medio de la consola con React Native CLI?. Estoy utilizando "react-native-background-geolocation" y un botón de tipo switch para activar y desactivar la funcionalidad. Actualmente cuando se activa el switch, llega una notificación y se obtiene la ubicación del usuario unicamente en primer plano. Este es el código actual

```
import {PermissionsAndroid, Switch } from 'react-native';
import BackgroundGeolocation, {Location} from "react-native-background-geolocation";

export default function Map() {
  const [userCoordinates, setUserCoordinates] = useState<LatLng[]>([])
  const [markerUbi, setMarkerUbi] = useState<Location | null>(null)
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false)
  const [location, setLocation] = useState('')

  const startTracking = () => {
    BackgroundGeolocation.ready({
      desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.DESIRED_ACCURACY_HIGH,
      stationaryRadius: 50,
      distanceFilter: 50,
      notification: {
        title: 'Background tracking',
        text: 'enabled',
      },
      debug: false,
      startOnBoot: true,
      stopOnTerminate: false,
    })
    BackgroundGeolocation.onLocation((location: Location) => {
      console.log('[BackgroundGeolocation]', location)
      setMarkerUbi(location)
      setUserCoordinates((coor) => [
        ...coor,
        {
          latitude: location.coords.latitude,
          longitude: location.coords.longitude,
        },
      ])
      setLocation(JSON.stringify(location, null, 2));
    });
    BackgroundGeolocation.start();
  }
  const stopTracking = () => {
    BackgroundGeolocation.stop()
  }
  const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          title: 'Location',
          message: 'Location?',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask',
          buttonNegative: 'Deny',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        }
      );
      return granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;
    } catch (err) {
      return false
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (enabled) {
      startTracking()
    } else {
      stopTracking()
    }
    return () => {
      stopTracking()
    };
  }, [enabled]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getLocation = async () => {
      const result = await requestLocationPermission()
    
      if (result) {
        const location = await BackgroundGeolocation.getCurrentPosition({})
        console.log('[BackgroundGeolocation]', location)
        setMarkerUbi(location)
        setUserCoordinates((coor) => [
          ...coor,
          {
            latitude: location.coords.latitude,
            longitude: location.coords.longitude,
          },
        ]);
        setLocation(JSON.stringify(location, null, 2));
      }
    };
    
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      getLocation()
    }, 10000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval)
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Click to toggle BackgroundGeolocation</Text>
      <Switch
        value={enabled}
        onValueChange={(value) => setEnabled(value)}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
type LatLng = {
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
};
```